# Check if Object is instance of String, HashMap, or HashMap[ ]

Tags: java, types, casting

I have an Object in java. Is there a way to check if an object is an instance of a String, HashMap, or HashMap[ ] before actually casting it to those objects?

If not, as it seems counterintuitive that the above would work, is there a way to cast it into each object, and test something about the newly casted object to see if its in fact the type of object into which it was casted?

Comment: Instead of using `instanceof` you can always, of course, cast to the presumed object type and listen for the `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @HotLicks: True. One small difference is that if `obj` is `null`, then `(obj instanceof ____)` will be `false`, but `((____) obj)` will not cause an exception to be raised.

Comment: Your design is suspect if you have to use `instanceof`. You're checking to see if you have a String, a HashMap, or a HashMap array? Where's the abstraction and information hiding in that? Java's an *object-oriented* language. I don't know what problem you're solving, but it sounds like you're lost. You should think of a better abstraction than this.

Comment: @ruakh -- Correct.  (And I wasn't advocating the use of exception catching vs `instanceof`, just pointing out that it would work too.)

Comment: check this POST 

[SOLVED] - How to check if a string is a double safely in JAVA
http://hongouru.blogspot.com.uy/2016/02/solved-how-to-check-if-string-is-double.html

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes:

```
 if(obj instanceof String)
 {
     String str = (String) obj;
     .
     .
     .
 }
```

By the way, to clarify regarding this:

> […] test something about the newly casted object to see if its in fact the type of object into which it was casted?

You *cannot* cast something into an invalid type. If `obj` has type `String`, then `((Integer)obj)` will cause a `ClassCastException` to be raised at run-time.

Comment: One thing to note, is that `instanceof` returns false when obj is null

Comment: So if I out.println( ) the object and I see "[Ljava.lang.Object;@4296e599" what does this mean? I thought it was a Map or HashMap but I get false for these when testing instance of.

Comment: That means that it has type `Object[]`. You can use `System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString((Object[]) ____))`, where `____` is the variable-name, to print out the elements of the array.

Comment: I meet this problem in the onsite interview yesterday. The interviewer asked me to sum (Collection<Object> objects).    The objects are ( string, number, List,  Set or HashMap).  I need to check the obj's type, and sum the values of the objects. Skip the strings of Objects.   Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for the [`instanceof`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) operator.

> The instanceof operator compares an object to a specified type. You
>   can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance
>   of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular
>   interface.

Example: `"Hello" instanceof String` would return `true` while `new Integer(5) instanceof String` would return `false`.